# How to get the child entity in Entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two table A,B , their relationship is 1 to 1, i have a method to get the info of A,

and there is a property B in the entity A, but after i user the method detach(A), found

the property B of entity A is null, i just want to return a detached entity to client side.

could you help me how to get a detached entity A contains property B?

Code snip

```
var a = Context.A.Include('B').Where(i.id=1) //the property B of entity a is not null
Context.Detach(a) ;// after executing this method the property B of entity a is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Daniel Simmons @ http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6c0aa93e-7fdf-475c-86ea-d5caac918329:

> Detaching graphs is a big pain in the rear. Frankly, unless your graph is very shallow, I wouldn't even try it. You have to take the graph apart from the bottom up and then reattach the entities in memory. Microsoft has not provided a pattern for us to do this and they aren't giving us a method for it in the next version.

Alternatively, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357601/290343) which might help you, or alternatively [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502467/290343).

Comment: Thanks a lot, your post help me to resolve the problem. i set the property MergeOption to MergeOption.NoTracking.